# Sometimes the dropdown menu appears, sometimes it doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, dropdown, menubar

```
import Logo1 from "../../AssetsMain/Img/logo.png";
import "./Navbar6css.css";

const Navbar6 = () => {
    return (
        <div className="navigation-fixed-wrapper" style={{ top: '0px' }}>
            <nav id="navigation4" className="container navigation navigation-landscape" style={{ width: '1423px' }}>

                <div className="nav-header"><a className="nav-brand" href="index.html">
                    <img className="Navbar-Image" style={{ height: '40px' }} src={Logo1} alt="file-not-found" id="main_logo" /></a>
                    <div className="nav-toggle"></div>
                </div>

                <div className="nav-menus-wrapper">
                    <span className="nav-menus-wrapper-close-button">✕</span>
                    <ul className="nav-menu align-to-right">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li className="dropdown">
                            {/* <a href="AboutUs">About Us
                            <span className="submenu-indicator submenu-indicator-chevron"></span>
                            </a> */}
                            <a href="#">About Us
                                <span className="submenu-indicator submenu-indicator-chevron"></span></a>
                            <ul className="dropdown-menu nav-submenu" style={{ right: 'auto' }}>
                                <li><a href="Chn">Chn</a></li>
                                <li><a href="Drs">Drs</a></li>
                                <li><a href="Ads">Ads</a></li>
                                <li><a href="AboutUs">About Us </a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                          <li className='dropdown'><a href="OG">O Cs
                            <span className="submenu-indicator submenu-indicator-chevron"></span></a>
                            <ul className="dropdown-menu nav-submenu" style={{ right: 'auto' }}>
                                <li><a href="OG">OG</a></li>
                                <li><a href="IF">IF</a></li>
                                <li><a href="T">T</a></li>
                             </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="OP">OP</a></li>
                        <li><a href="LN">LN</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </div>
                <div className="nav-overlay-panel"></div>
            </nav >
        </div >

    )
}

export default Navbar6
```

On hover the font colors changes, but why is the dropdown menu not working?

Comment: Does the page include the Bootstrap CSS? Does it include the Bootstrap Javascript?

Comment: i am trying to apply bootstrap and js globally so i have included in index.html "<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../src/AssetsMain/Css/bootstrap.min.css" />" but dropdown is not working , while on hoover text color is being changed.

Comment: Your comments shows just the CSS, not the JS.